# Batch: Only run if parent folder contains "word"

Tags: batch-file

I'm looking for a way to only allow my batch file to proceed IF it is placed inside of a directory containing a certain word. My pseudocode is as follows:

```
IF parentDirectory contains some "word" GOTO start
ELSE echo "error message here" GOTO end
```

What are my options for achieving this?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Why write pseudo code when you can read the help file for the `IF` command and it will show you the exact syntax for using `IF...ELSE..`. Open up a cmd prompt and type: `IF /?` to read the helpf file for the `IF` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something I whipped up:

```
@echo off

for %%A in ("%~f0\..") do set "folder=%%~nxA"

echo.%folder% | findstr /C:"desk" 1>nul

if errorlevel 1 (
  echo "error message here"
  goto end
) else (
  goto start
)

:start
echo starting

:end
echo end!
```

Let's step through it:

```
@echo off
```

`%~f0` is the path to batch file; this loops through the parts of the path and on the last iteration `folder` is the parent folder for the batch file.

```
for %%A in ("%~f0\..") do set "folder=%%~nxA"
```

Now we pipe the parent folder name into `findstr`; the `/C` switch is the search word. `1>nul` discards the output.

```
echo.%folder% | findstr /C:"desk" 1>nul
```

`findstr` reports error levels based on whether it found something, so we can check them to find out what to do next:

```
if errorlevel 1 (
  echo "error message here"
  goto end
) else (
  goto start
)
```

And here are just some sample labels to go along with your pseudocode.

```
:start
echo starting

:end
echo end!
```

I was testing this in my Desktop folder, hence the "desk" in the `findstr` call.

Comment: You're a star. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume you want to check the current working directory which could be different from the batch file directory.  Regardless of that this same concept can be used if you assign the command line argument to an environmental variable

```
@echo off

if NOT "%cd:word=%"=="%cd%" (
    GOTO START
) else (
    echo Error
    GOTO END
)
```

Comment: Great that it can be used both ways. Thank you!

Comment: Additionally, for the batch file to proceed only if its parent contains `word`, you would use `%0` so perhaps you could precede the `if` line with `CD /D "%~dp0"`.